# Update graph data in SQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, graph, common-table-expression

I need to traverse and update the graph in SQL.

To put this into prospective, I'll give an example:

- Every company can represent other company on a given subject.
- Companies can represent each other, but not for the same subject

This assumes tables like:

`companies(id)`, `representations(source_id, destination_id, subject)`.

But the rule is that when my company is no longer representing yours on a given subject, then no companies down the chain from mine can represent my company on the same subject.

I hope you understand what I mean.

So with the simple data like:

```
C1:
--sell--> C2
--pay--> C3

C2:
--sell--> C3
--pay--> C1

C3:
--mail--> C1
--sell--> C4

C4:
--deliver-->C1
```

Now, we remove the representation (I should have called it relation) `C2--sell-->C3` we should end up the following structure (`[X]` - removed):

```
C1:
--sell--> C2
--pay--> C3

C2:
[X]--sell--> C3
--pay--> C1

C3:
--mail--> C1
[X]--sell--> C4

C4:
--deliver-->C1
```

So the question is how is it possible to select all the companies, that are down the chain from mine for a given subject?

I suppose recursive CTE expression is the only way to do it.

**NOTES:**

- The structure is not a tree, it is an ordered cyclic graph.
- Graph database isn't an option for now (this is only a small part of the system)
- The updates don't need to be immediate and it's ok for them to be eventually consistent (talking about few seconds to minutes).

Comment: Are there cycles in the graph? If the graph is acyclic that helps a fair bit. Working with a cyclic digraph with SQL CTEs could be "fun".

Comment: Giving example data to demonstrate the normal case and corner cases may help get an exact answer.  Then we have imperical data to work on, rather than inferring details from your description.

Comment: It is cyclic for better or worse :(

Comment: From the "companies can represent each other, but not for the same subject" bit I would understand that you have acyclic graphs, but lots of them, one graph for each subject.

Comment: @jpe yes, that's correct. I've added somewhat simplistic example of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need to maintain a transitive closure of the graph for each subject. Look at [a paper about how to implement an incremental evaluation system (IES) with SQL](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/libkin/papers/tc-sql.pdf), seems to be able to do the trick. The paper has extensive SQL examples for directed acyclic, undirected and arbitrary directed graphs.

It appears that for each of your subject the graph is acyclic, which is fortunately the simplest case.

Comment: Look at it! It's damn well written. I would make the text worse by copying it here.

Comment: yeah, will have to take my time to read. Ha-ha, no no copying that here :)

Comment: @DmytriiNagirniak: Before the "heavy"-reading of papers, here's a "light"-intoduction into hierarchical models in SQL and especially the Transitive Closure: [Models for Hirarchical data](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data) by Bill Karwin

Comment: @ypercube This is a great presentation and a really good introduction to the problem.

Comment: @ypercube did you notice that the question was about graphs, not trees? :)

Comment: Closure can represent directed graphs, too. (acyclic easier then graphs with cycles).